# how to get the id of each dropdown and textarea row

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-designer

Not sure what is the right approach to tackle this

I want to control te textarea Reason based on what is selected in the dropdown list. As you can see below i have got to the stage where i can get the attribute id of each row of the DropDown list Status But i can't get the attr id of each textarea Reason

My final result should be if a user selects declined then the user but enter a reason and if deactivated must enter a date. Thanks in advance

```
<tr>
<td class="ms-vb"><span dir="none">
<select class="ms-RadioText" title="Status" id="WebPartManager_g_31f0d9e1_72a0_4ef2_b286_7c30cd0fda1f_ff5_3_ctl00_DropDownChoice" name="WebPartManager$g_31f0d9e1_72a0_4ef2_b286_7c30cd0fda1f$ff5_3$ctl00$DropDownChoice">
<option value="Provisionally Approved" selected="selected">Provisionally Approved
</option>
<option value="Approved">Approved</option>
<option value="Declined">Declined</option>
<option value="Deactivated">Deactivated</option>
</select><br>
</span></td>
<td class="ms-vb">
<span dir="none">
<textarea dir="none" class="ms-long" title="Reason" id="WebPartManager_g_31f0d9e1_72a0_4ef2_b286_7c30cd0fda1f_ff11_3_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" cols="20" rows="6" name="WebPartManager$g_31f0d9e1_72a0_4ef2_b286_7c30cd0fda1f$ff11_3$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" style="display: none;">Test3</textarea><br>
</span></td>

</tr>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("textarea").hide(); 
 $("input[title$='DeActivatedDate']").hide(); 


 $("tr select[title='Status']").change(function () {




        var selectedValue = $(this).find("option:selected").text();


        if (selectedValue == 'Declined')
        {


       alert('You need to type in a Reason if STATUS is DECLINED!');


        //i'm getting the id of each dropdown row here
        var select_id = $(this).attr('id');  
        var b = $("#" + select_id).text();
        alert(select_id);
        //i can get the id of each Dropdown  of each row


         //i'm getting the id of each textarea row here
        var textarea_id = $("tr td textarea").attr('id'); 
        var c = $("#" + textarea_id).text();
        alert(textarea_id);

        //i'm only getting the attr id of the first textarea but not the other



       }

        if (selectedValue == 'Deactivated')
        {

        alert('You need to select a De-Activated Date if STATUS IS DEACTIVATED!');
       }




      });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`attr` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr):

> gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set

So this:

```
var select_id = $(this).attr('id');
```

works because `this` is the `<select>` element so there is only one element. The `<textarea>` one:

```
var textarea_id = $("tr td textarea").attr('id');
```

Just grabs the `id` attribute of the first `<textarea>`. If you want all the `<textarea>` elements, use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each):

```
$("tr td textarea").each(function() {
    var textarea_id = this.id;
    var content     = $(this).text();
    alert(textarea_id);
});
```

You don't need to use `attr` to get an ID if you have a DOM object (`this` inside the `each`), you can just access the attribute directly.

If you only want the `<textarea>` that's in the same row as the `<select>` (as noted in the comments), then you can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to walk up the DOM a bit and then [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) to come back down:

```
var textarea_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('textarea').attr('id');
```

And there are multiple `<textarea>` elements in the table row and you want them all, then combine both approaches:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('textarea').each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. but i don't want the id of all the textarea.I wonly want the one thats on the same row as the dropdownlist.I need to compare the selected item with the value in the textarea box. if the selcted value is declined then user must add some text in the corresponding row in the textarea.

Comment: Thanks mu is too short will give that a try let you know

Comment: Thanks alot mu is short YOU ROCK